# How can I CREATE USER with a dynamic username?

Tags: mysql

In a MySQL script I would like to do something like this:

```
SET @username = CONCAT(DATABASE(), "-1@`%`");
CREATE USER @username;
```

but I can't resolve the syntax error in the CREATE USER line.

Is there a way to escape the inline variable so that CREATE USER can have a dynamically created user?

Comment: You cannot use parameters in a `CREATE USER` statement AFAIK.

Comment: Also prepared statements is not an option.

Comment: @tombom: Why not?  One can use `CREATE USER` [in prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) since MySQL v5.1.

Comment: Oh, I had a try and at first it didn't work. But it was cause of missing privileges. Misread the error message at first, don't ask how and why :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html):

```
set @sql=concat("create user '", database(), "-haha", "'@'%' identified by 'whatever';");
prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;

select @sql;

select * from mysql.user where user = 'playground-haha';
```

Comment: Thanks @tombom. This works great in the Workbench SQL Editor, but I'm having trouble executing it within a database creation script from code. I load my db creation script text (which includes several CREATE TABLE statements) and execute the script text from a Command in ADO.net. But the addition of just the "set @sql=concat("blah", "blah")" line causes the script to fail. I guess I need to escape "set @sql..." one more level?

Comment: Finally got it working. Needed to set 'allow user variables' to true on the connection string. Learned from another SO thread. Very non-obvious to me.